# Magento 1 - How to get a products small image in the side cart?

Tags: cart, image, magento-1.7

I used this code to display a Thumbnail image :

```
<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(50, 50)?>
```

but i would like to display the small image. I used that to my sidebar cart

Comment: Hey Amirov, did you have any progress on this question?

Answer (score 12):

You can use the catalog image helper to get any type of image.

```
$_product = $_item->getProduct();
echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(50,50);
```

If I'm correct `$_item->getProduct()` is an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`, if not you'll need to load the instance first per item

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId());
echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(50,50);
```

Comment: How can i get small image in View order inside customer account like -> https://snag.gy/2KUce6.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src='.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(225, 225).' width=\'225\' height=\'225\'/>
```